# Why does SonarCloud show that everything is fine?

Tags: c#, .net, sonarcloud

I'm working on a c# .net6 project and I'm trying to integrate SonarCloud using GitHub Actions.
I have a build and sonarcloud workflow that looks like this:

```
name: .NET

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Setup .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
        with:
          dotnet-version: 6.0.x
      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore
        working-directory: Backend
      - name: Build
        run: dotnet build --no-restore
        working-directory: Backend
      - name: Test
        run: dotnet test --no-build --verbosity normal
        working-directory: Backend
  sonarcloud:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
        with:
          # Disabling shallow clone is recommended for improving relevancy of reporting
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: SonarCloud Scan
        uses: sonarsource/sonarcloud-github-action@master
        env:
          GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
          SONAR_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.SONAR_TOKEN }}
```

The build works fine and the tests are passing but sonarcloud is always showing no issue despite writing some code smells and duplications on purpose to see if it works.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3dvMo.png)

I see that sonarcloud is seeing all of my code so that shouldn't be a problem.
I have a **sonar-project.properties** file and an analysis is running every time there is either a push or a pull request so I guess the setup is good but I don't get why it doesn't report any issue, either code smells or duplicate code. Are there any more setups I should've made?

Answer (score 0):

At [SonarSource](https://github.com/SonarSource/sonarcloud-github-action#do-not-use-this-github-action-if-you-are-in-the-following-situations) it states to not use the action if

> You want to analyze a .NET solution

But instead:

> Follow our interactive tutorial for Github Actions after importing your project directly in SonarCloud

That's probably because you have to call `dotnet-sonarscanner begin` before executing `dotnet test` and finish the analysis by invoking `dotnet-sonarscanner end`.

BTW: This also introduces a problem if you want to analyse PRs from a fork, since secrets are not passed to such PRs and using other triggers introduces high security risks. (see [github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests](https://securitylab.github.com/research/github-actions-preventing-pwn-requests/))